# Why is my Selenium xpath expression returning an [object attribute] instead of an element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm making a scraper that will through my webpage and grab all of the links. A lot of the links are in closed list also known as a tree. Therefore, I found the xpath that holds all of the links. I ran the following xpath in google inspect and it ran perfectly fine giving me the following output.

```
var result=$x("//div[@id='index__tree']//a[contains(text(),doku.php)]/@href")

result[0].value
"/doku.php?ihome"
result[4].value
"/doku.php?start"
```

I than transferred the xpath into selenium code:

```
a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='index__tree']//a[contains(text(),doku.php)]/@href")

for aa in a:
        print(aa)
```

I then ran the code and received the following error:

```
opening browser
Login Successful
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wiki.py", line 49, in <module>
    a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='index__tree']//a[contains(text(),doku.php)]/@href")
  File "/home/aevans/wikiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 410, in find_elements_by_xpath
    return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/home/aevans/wikiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "/home/aevans/wikiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/aevans/wikiProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@id='index__tree']//a[contains(text(),doku.php)]/@href" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
  (Session info: headless chrome=73.0.3683.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.86,platform=Linux 3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='index__tree']//a[contains(text(),doku.php)]/@href")
for aa in a:
    print(aa)
```

with

```
a = [elem.get_attribute("href") for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='index__tree']//a[contains(text(),doku.php)]")]

for aa in a:
    print(aa)
```

Notice I removed the "/@href" from the end of your selector.

The Selenium selectors must return a WebElement. By specifying the "/@href", it returned the href attribute of that element instead of the element itself.

The method get_attribute(attribute_name) returns the attribute of an element. Then, you can loop through it.

Comment: Did you mean to add the '[" after a=[ elem. I'm getting a syntax error on the for loop with this code. I tried to remove the [ but I received an error on the "for" in "for elem in ... "

Comment: I forgot to add a closing bracket "]" at the end of the list comprehension. Edited

Comment: The orginial xpath was grabbing me about 157 links. This code is getting me about 20. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you making sure the script is waiting until all the links are loaded?

Comment: I added a time.sleep(5) in the script and it doesn't produce more links

Comment: @Ant What you do locally in the dev tools is going to be very different from when you run the code. There are potential timing issues or you scrolled the page manually and then pulled the data in the dev tools vs just running the script, etc.